# loop that works between 9:30 to 5:30 every weekday in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I want the page to load every 10 seconds only on weekdays from 9:30 to 5:30 but cant make it work . my code is:

```
   ~function checkTime() {
    var d = new Date(); // current time
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    if (hours >= 17 || hours <= 18) {
        setInterval(() => {
            location.reload();
        }, 5000);

        }

    }~
```

Comment: Do you actually call the function anywhere?

Comment: no its only afunctio i want to execute fora specific time period

Comment: Neither does the `if` condition fulfill your time restrictions nor does it make sense to start an interval in that same `if` block. You want an interval that constantly checks the time and only does something (e.g. `location.reload()`) if a condition is fulfilled.

Comment: yes the location.reload() should work only between 9:30-5:30 on weekdays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below checks the time every 10 secs and if it meets the conditions, logs **reload the page** to console.

```js
const refreshPage = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const date = new Date();
    const day = date.getDay();
    const isWeekDay = day > 0 && day < 6;
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const isBetweenTime = checkTime(hours, minutes);
    if (isWeekDay && isBetweenTime) {
      console.log('reload the page');
      // location.reload();
    }
  }, 10000);
}

const checkTime = (hours, minutes) => {
  const totalMins = (hours * 60 + minutes);
  const min = 570; // 9:30 = 9 * 60 + 30;
  const max = 1050; // 17:30 = 17 * 60 + 30;
  return totalMins >= min && totalMins <= max;
}


refreshPage();
```